# python 3.8 error with cross validation Implementation

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, python-3.8

When I run the following code from a tutorial, I keep getting the following error at the end in almost every video I attempt.

Source: https://pythonprogramming.net/k-means-from-scratch-2-machine-learning-tutorial/?completed=/k-means-from-scratch-machine-learning-tutorial/

I get the following error:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation

ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn
```

I did pip installs, changing the way cross_validation is stated based on other suggestions but I still can't solve it.

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should *not* be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out); please see how to create a [mcve]. Arguably, you don't need a wall of code to demonstrate that you have an issue with the imports in the 2nd line of your code...

Comment: It looks like the tutorial you're following was written a long time ago, and code examples are inconsistent with current versions of scikit-learn. You probably want: [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find `cross_validation` as a library in sklearn.

You need to use `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate` as per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html). This has already been answered [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html).

I also suggest going through the documentation of the functions you use to gain a better understanding of what you are doing.